# How to let people download a file from your computer

Tags: download, extensions

I am creating an extension for QGIS (I'm new to this). So, users can choose two different file types(A and B) and if they choose A. I give them a file related to A which they can directly save to their computer system. I have the file in my device. How do I let other people to have that file?

Comment: Your description is a little vague, could you expand on it a bit more. As it reads, although it's a QGIS extension, there isn't any spatial component to your question so it's likely to get closed for being off-topic; perhaps this is more a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a GIS question.

You cannot reliably let users download a file from your own physical computer at home, so essentially what you ask for is a file hosting service.

You upload the file there and give users a download link to the service.

People use Google Drive or such for that. Keep in mind to look at the Terms of Service and check if your usage will conform to that (especially if your data file is used in a commercial/for-profit plugin).